# localhost load JSP page correctly , But with self IP does not load it correctly in IE

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, internet-explorer

In a maven project jsp page,

localhost load JSP page correctly in IE , But with self IP(By pass with proxy) does not load it correctly..

There is **no such a problem in Google Chrome**, for both url it works. 
But in **internet explorer only work for localhost**,when apply with self IP it crashed. 
There are java script validations too.

It is **IE11** version.

Comment: Check what is the Document mode? Open ur IE11 browser. **Press F12, go to Emulation tab and u will find document mode drop down** .Set the proper Document mode from the drop down. It should work.